# Perl variable interpolation in string and substitution at the same time

Tags: perl, substitution

I have the silly question

```
given($num){
...
when($num >= 13 and $num <= 99) return "$num_in_eng{$num}teen" =~ s/tt/t/;
...
}
```

but it gave an error
"Can't modify the string in substitution near s/tt/t/g;

```
$_ = "$num_in_eng{$num}teen";
s/tt/t/;
```

This work fine

Comment: i used it , doesn't gave an explanation
"You aren't to allowed to assign to the item indicated or otherwise try to change it, such as with an auto increment"

Comment: You can perform `s///` on variables, not plain strings. `s///r` might be another matter.

Comment: mpapec: you should really post an answer with the `/r` modifier since it isn't widely used

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign to a string literal.  It wouldn't make sense to say `"foo" = "bar"` either.

If you try to use the match operator `=~` with a substitution (for example, a regex term starting with `s`, like in `s/foo/bar/`), the result of the substitution will be assigned to the left hand side.  If that is a literal, you will get this error.

It does not matter that you actually used string interpolation to create the literal.

Using a local variable and substituting its contents like you have shown the right solution.  You can also use a named variable instead of the "default" `$_`:

```
$foo = whatever();
$foo =~ s/tt/t/;
return $foo;
```